# Connection to SFTP using Jsch throwing NullPointer

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am writing a basic application using jsch to try and connect with an AWS SFTP server.

I am using jsch version
`implementation group: 'com.github.mwiede', name: 'jsch', version: '0.2.11'`

When I try to make a connection it gets disconnected immediately after a handshake and my console shows this error code.

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:605)
```

With this simple connection code

```
try{
    Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

    Hashtable<String, String> config = new Hashtable<>();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    JSch sch = new JSch();
    JSch.setConfig(config);
    JSch.setLogger(new TestLogger(logger));

    JSch.setConfig("kex", "diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256");
    JSch.setConfig("mac.s2c", "hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com");
    JSch.setConfig("mac.c2s", "hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com");

    JSch.setConfig("enable_server_sig_algs", "yes");
    JSch.setConfig("prefer_known_host_key_types", "yes");
    JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", "ssh-rsa");

    Session session = sch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);

    system.print.out.ln("Opening session for SFTP");
    sch.addIdentity(rsaKey);

    System.print.out.ln("Attempting to connect");
    session.connect(60 * 1000);

}catch (Exception e){
    System.print.out.ln("Error: " + e);
}
```

And below is the info of what is happening during the connection

```
Attempting to connect
INFO | Connecting to HOSTNAME port PORT
INFO | Connection established
INFO | Remote version string: SSH-2.0-AWS_SFTP_1.1
INFO | Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO | CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO | SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO | SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO | kex: server: diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO | kex: server: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
INFO | kex: server: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr
INFO | kex: server: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr
INFO | kex: server: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
INFO | kex: server: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
INFO | kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO | kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
INFO | kex: server: 
INFO | kex: server: 
INFO | kex: client: diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO | kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO | kex: client: aes192-ctr
INFO | kex: client: aes192-ctr
INFO | kex: client: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
INFO | kex: client: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
INFO | kex: client: none
INFO | kex: client: none
INFO | kex: client: 
INFO | kex: client: 
INFO | kex: server->client aes192-ctr hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com none
INFO | kex: client->server aes192-ctr hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com none
INFO | Disconnecting from HOSTNAME port PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much [dave_tompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) and [Rob Spoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180351/rob-spoor). I looked at my dependency build.gradle and noticed that for some reason another one of my modules included the jcraft.jsch 0.1.54 library in the build.gradle. I removed that and now I am able to make an sftp connection.